# Is there any research on the long term effect of dry foods on dogs?

Tags: dogs, health, diet

Ancestors of dogs and cats mostly ate meat in the wild as well as after domestication. True that they ate hard bones. Nowadays we use dry kibbles mostly because that is cheaper and easier. Given that these are made *very* dry to improve the shelf life, they must be somewhat abrasive to the throat and esophagus. At least my dog gulps its meals within seconds, too fast for any saliva to lubricate I assume. I wonder if this constant abrasion can cause harm over 12-16 year life span of a large dog.

My question is, has there been any studies on the long term effect of dry kibbles on dogs health?

Edit: I am looking specifically for any academic studies on the abrasiveness since it is 'unnatural'.

Comment: Found [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6515799/), but it mentions dry food only in passing.

Answer (score -2):

Using simple logic, such studies are not likely to exist. Why? Simply because the dry food is "fast food", maybe even "junk food". Such studies, done properly, would be able to prove only one thing - dry food is unhealthy.

The same discussion happens about food for people - the kind of stuff we are forced to buy from the supermarkets, full of additives and chemicals and whatnot. There will be no real study about its long-term effects on humans - simply because the result is known already.

Now consider that there is a [**massively relevant study**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_China_Study) saying that even "proper" food can be very dangerous for health. So even more reason for studies on junk food to not exist. Or, if they exist, to not be really trustworthy - especially if they claim that junk food is good.

Note: it should be our burden as paying customers to initiate researches to prove that the products we buy are good or bad. It should be the task of the manufacturers to run these studies, publish the results, and then we can find the eventual flaws. But if no manufacturer ran such a study (or, at least, they did not publish the results), then they most likely have good reasons.

Another note: comparing one dry food with another dry food is not relevant, regardless of the level of quality. The reference for quality is natural food, an in the case of dogs, the natural food is very wet (i.e., fresh meat).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142720/discussion-on-answer-by-virolino-is-there-any-research-on-the-long-term-effect-o); please do not continue the discussion here.**